# Unable to select constructor with argument resolved from another registered instance property

Tags: c#, dryioc

The following example will register the property of the applicationconfiguration instance into the container, the next registration will then use that property for the constructor of the console writer.

```
container.Register(
                Made.Of(r => ServiceInfo.Of<ApplicationConfiguration>(), f => f.SomeConfigurationValue),
                serviceKey: nameof(ApplicationConfiguration.SomeConfigurationValue));

container.Register(
            Made.Of(
                () => new ConsoleWriter(
                    Arg.Of<string>(nameof(ApplicationConfiguration.SomeConfigurationValue)))));
```

However, we would prefer to not register the property in the container, but using some kind of expression to directly select the property of the registered application configuration instance.
We would like to have something that looks like this:

```
var typedMadeString = Made.Of(
                r => ServiceInfo.Of<ApplicationConfiguration>(),
                f => f.Property);
container.Register(
                Made.Of(
                    () => new ConsoleWriter(Arg.Of<string>(typedMadeString))));
```

But this does not work, the following exception is thrown (which we expected):

```
Unable to resolve String {ServiceKey=DryIoc.Made+TypedMade`1[System.String]} 
as parameter "message"
in DryIoc.Program.ConsoleWriter.
Where no service registrations found
and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0
and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0
```

Is there any way to achieve this? This are the sample classes we have. We only want to register these two classes

```
private class ApplicationConfiguration
    {
        internal string SomeConfigurationValue => "Hello World";
    }

    private class ConsoleWriter
    {
        private readonly string _message;

        internal ConsoleWriter(string message)
        {
            this._message = message;
        }

        internal void Write(int times = 1)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) Console.WriteLine(this._message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  option 1:

    c.Register<ConsoleWriter>(
      Made.Of(() => new ConsoleWriter(Arg.Index<string>(0)), 
      _ => c.Resolve<ApplicationConfiguration>().SomeConfigurationValue));

  option 2: if you change the ConsoleWriter constructor to public

    c.Register<ConsoleWriter>(made: Parameters.Of
     .Name("message", _ => c.Resolve<ApplicationConfiguration>().SomeConfigurationValue));

  option 3: the simplest, may be the best one to use.

    c.RegisterDelegate<ConsoleWriter>(
        r => new ConsoleWriter(r.Resolve<ApplicationConfiguration>().SomeConfigurationValue));
```